# How Can I Filter Filtered Data in DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, search, filter

I'm Having a Problem in filtering Data in Data Grid View, My code works if I use 1 search filter but if I use 2 search filter it's not, first I need to filter it by Courts then the other one is by venue or location

Please give me any idea on how can I make this code works, thank you

My Code:

```
Private Sub Searchbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Searchbtn.Click

    'Search Code

        If Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Item to be Search", "IBP Legal Aid Case Management System - Legal Aid Case File - Search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text) Then
            Me.TblLegalAidCaseFileBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Court/Agency] like '%{0}%'", Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text)
        ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.VenueComboBox.Text) Then
            Me.TblLegalAidCaseFileBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Court/Agency] like '%{0}%' and Venue like '%{0}%'", Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text, Me.VenueComboBox.Text)
        Else
            RefreshData()
            Return
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way if-else statements work is that it will execute the first one that meets the condition. In your 1-filter case, it will fulfill this condition `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text)` and thus execute that line. However, in your 2-filter case, it will check the first condition `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text)` and execute that line too, since the condition is actually fulfilled.

An easy way to solve your problem directly is to swap the conditions. Starting with the condition that is the hardest to fulfill. Which will look like this (I nested your conditions to make it cleaner):

```
(Code before...)
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text) Then
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.VenueComboBox.Text) Then
        Me.TblLegalAidCaseFileBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Court/Agency] like '%{0}%' and Venue like '%{1}%'", Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text, Me.VenueComboBox.Text)
    Else
        Me.TblLegalAidCaseFileBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Court/Agency] like '%{0}%'", Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text)
Else (Code after...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response about my problem but it's still not working, Maybe It's syntax is incorrect here

Me.TblLegalAidCaseFileBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Court/Agency] like '%{0}%' AND Venue like '%{0}%'", Me.Court_AgencyComboBox.Text, Me.VenueComboBox.Text) because it is not letting two string filter to search data

Comment: What's the error given ? I don't know about VB's syntax so I can't see the problem in your syntax

Comment: `'%{0}%' and Venue like '%{1}%'"` << can you try using `1`?

Comment: Problem was with the `'%{0}%' parts. The number represents the index (0-based) of item that is inserted to its position. The specific error should be that the second parameter isn't used at all in the original code (First item used twice).